# How to solve this error Minified React error #200; visit

Tags: reactjs

I try this code. but it give errror:`Minified React error #200; visit`.

```
// change code below this line
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id='challenge-node'>
        <h1>My First React Component!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />,document.getElementById('chllenge-node'));
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it work fine for me.

```
// change code below this line
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id='challenge-node'>
        <h1>My First React Component!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />,document.getElementById('challenge-node'));
```

There are some spelling mistacks. That i can correct then it work fine.